Recent breakthroughs with applied origins
Historically, the boundary between pure mathematics and its applications was much less defined. However, with the increasing complexity of modern mathematics and the resulting need for specialization, mathematical research often evolves away from its original motivations. While there are numerous cases where theoretical results have found unexpected applications, I am interested in the converse: instances where applied fields have directly inspired breakthroughs in pure mathematics.
One well-known example is the work of Candelas et al. [1], who calculated the number of degree-three curves on a quintic Calabi–Yau manifold (317,206,375). String Theory may be controversial among physicists, but I think this serves as an example of how insights from outside mathematics can drive advancements in enumerative geometry.
For the purposes of this question, let’s define "recent" as within the past 50 years. Are there other examples where insights or techniques from an applied field have led to major progress in pure mathematics?
Candelas, Philip; de la Ossa, Xenia C.; Green, Paul S.; Parkes, Linda, A pair of Calabi-Yau manifolds as an exactly soluble superconformal theory., Nucl. Phys., B 359, No. 1, 21-74 (1991). ZBL1098.32506.

Maybe "compressed sensing"

Maybe the concept of PAC learning.

I didn't see it until after posting, but this question is closely related:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368691/recent-uses-of-applied-mathematics-in-pure-mathematics?rq=1

See the article by Sturmfels, Can biology lead to new theorems?

@TimothyChow Thanks for that article. That’s exactly the sort of question I had in mind.

If you include mathematical physics (string theory, QFT) to "applied mathematics", the breakthroughs are too numerous to list them here. Statistical mechanics is especially productive in its influence on pure mathematics.
Here is a very recent example not related to QFT or string theory. An important Connes' Embedding Conjecture from the theory of von Neumann algebras, has been apparently disproved by
the arguments from Computer Science (quantum computing):
MIP*=RE
(The complete paper is not published yet, given its size, it will take some time to verity, but it has already 348 citations on Google Scholar at the time of this writing).
More examples (just a selection of those which I encountered during my career). All of these are examples of breakthroughs in pure mathematics inspired by physics.
In 1987, Zograf and Takhtadzhyan made a breakthrough in the classical accessory parameter problem of uniformization theory by proving a conjecture of physicists Belavin, Polyakov and Zamolodchikov inspired by string theory.
In 1993, Kari Astala proved the old conjecture of Gehring and Reich by using ``thermodynamic formalism''. The proof has been substantially simplified since, but still uses the main idea which comes from statistical physics. More generally "thermodynamic formalism" is a part of pure mathematics
directly inspired by physics, see, for example this survey paper by David Ruelle on the influence of statistical mechanics on pure mathematics.
In the early 2000s Oded Schramm created the
SLE theory (Stochastic Loewner Equation, aka Schramm-Loewner evolution) on the boundary of probability and complex analysis. It was directly inspired by questions from physics (statistical mechanics, percolation theory, Cardy formula).
In 2005, Mukhin, Tarasov and Varchenko proved the B. and M. Shapiro Conjecture from real enumerative geometry by unexpected argument
from mathematical physics (Bethe-ansatz from statistical mechanics). In 2020 a
surprising connection of this former Shapiro conjecture with SLE has been found
(Peltola and Wang, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.08574 )
In cases 1,2,4, the initial problem had nothing to do with physics, and solving them by methods coming from physics was quite unexpected.
There are various opinions on this "unreasonable effectiveness of physics in pure mathematics", for example, Ruelle (loc. cit.) ascribes a deep philosophical meaning to it. Another opinion that I've heard is simply that "some physicists are very clever people, and when they start thinking of mathematics, they come with clever ideas" (this was proposed by V. G. Drinfeld when he was listening my talk on Astala's theorem).

Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350440/connes-embedding-conjecture-is-false

Very informative and interesting answer (as usual) , thanks for sharing !

The link to Zograf and Takhtadzhyan  leads to general mathnet site at least for me. Is it that paper: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1988v060n01ABEH003160/meta?casa_token=qoaKKXH6LnsAAAAA:WRUy0pCPIX8Fbl4_EVtClI2uhmg-b0-jHckEKFzMCLBXeo8j1cDQeItpHeHEBNjP1qACilThs8MxXqTT-mJt_aumNwU What is the link to "In 2020 a a surprising connection of this former Shapiro conjecture with SLE has been found." ?

The MIP*=RE example is excellent! I guess there are many examples from physics, and the lines dividing applied math from mathematical physics from physics are very blurry, if they exist at all.

@Gabe K I agree that there are very many examples from physics (beginning from Archimedes) but mathematical physics is not the same as pure mathematics. See the nice discussion of this in Ruelle's paper.

@Alexander Chervov: I inserted the link on "surprising connection" but for some reason it does not show it. The link is arxiv.org/pdf/2006.08574 And I fixed the link to Zograf anf Takhtajan. (With the link you propose, I was unable to verify that I am a human:-)

I would like to suggest the quantum-information-inspired work of David Roberson and coauthors on compact quantum groups.
Already in his PhD Roberson was working on quantum homomorphisms, inspired by the graph homomorphism game from quantum information theory [8].
With a number of coauthors, Roberson introduced the graph isomorphism game [1]. The consideration of quantum strategies for this non-local game leads to the relation on finite graphs of quantum isomorphism. This is a richer relation than that of classical graph isomorphism and the paper gives a pair of graphs on 24 vertices that are quantum isomorphic but not isomorphic. The paper also shows that the question of whether or not two graphs
are quantum isomorphic is undecidable.
In [6], Roberson along with Lupini and Mančinska established a “strong connection” between quantum information and the theory of quantum permutation groups (the quantum subgroups of the quantum permutation groups $S_N^+$ of Wang [10]). A graph $X$ with $N$ vertices has an automorphism group $G(X)\subseteq S_N$ as well as a quantum automorphism group $G^+(X) \subseteq S_N^+$.
On the one hand, Roberson and coauthors use ideas and results from quantum
information theory to prove new results about quantum permutation groups (particularly quantum automorphism groups of graphs). On the other hand, from the theory of quantum permutation groups, the existence of a tracial state (the Haar state) on the algebra associated to the quantum automorphism groups allows an equivalent definition of quantum isomorphism in the language of quantum permutation groups.
In [7], Roberson and Mančinska use representation theory from compact quantum groups to prove a quantum analogue of a result of Lováz that said that two graphs are isomorphic if and only if they admit the same number of homomorphisms from any graph. The quantum analogue here is that two graphs are quantum isomorphic if and only if they admit the same number of homomorphism from any planar graph. This result echos the difference between the (partition) tensor categories associated to the classical permutation group and the quantum permutation group — all partitions for the classical permutation group, but only the non-crossing partitions for the quantum permutation group. However, it must be pointed out that Roberson along with Kar, Seppelt and Zeman have recently provided a proof that avoids the compact quantum group machinery [4].
In [5], Kar, Prakash, and Roberson associate to each bisynchronous transitive non-local game a quantum permutation group, and to each quantum permutation group such a game may be associated (the latter not injectively). Once again the Haar state from the theory of compact quantum groups is used to prove results pertaining to quantum information theory.
Along the way, with coauthors, Roberson has answered a number of open problems in the theory of quantum automorphism groups: the existence of a graph with ‘genuine’ quantum symmetry but with finite dimensional $C(G^+(X))$ [9]; the existence of a graph with trivial classical automorphism group but non-trivial quantum automorphism group; for each finite group $G$ there exists a finite graph $X_c$ such that $G^+(X_c) \cong G$; for each finite group $G$ there exists a finite graph $X_q$ with $G(X_q) \cong
G$ but $G(X_q)\subsetneq  G^+(X_q)$ [2].
References
[1] A. Atseria, L. Mančinska, D. E. Roberson, R. Šámal, S. Severini, and A. Varvitsiotis, Quantum and non-signalling graph isomorphisms, J. Comb Theory, Series B, Volume 136, (2019), 289–328.
[2] J. van Dobben de Bruyn, E. Roberson, and S. Schmidt, Asymmetric graphs with quantum symmetry, arXiv:2311.04889 (2023).
[4] P. N. Kar, D. E. Roberson, T. Seppelt, and P. Zeman, NPA Hierarchy for Quantum Isomorphism and Homomorphism Indistinguishability, arXiv:2407.10635 (2024).
[5] P. N. Kar, J. Prakash, D. E. Roberson, Transitive nonlocal games, J. Math. Phys. 1 July 2024; 65 (7): 072202. https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0199344.
[6] M. Lupini, L. Mančinska and D.E. Roberson, Nonlocal games and quantum permutation groups, J. Funct. Anal. 279 (2020), 1–39.
[7] L. Mančinska and D. E. Roberson, Quantum isomorphism is equivalent to equality of homomorphism counts from planar graphs. In 2020 IEEE 61st Annual
Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS), (2020) pages 661—672
doi:10.1109/FOCS46700.2020.00067.
[8] D. Roberson, Variations on a Theme: Graph Homomorphims, PhD Thesis, University of Waterloo, (2013).
[9] D. Roberson and S. Schmidt, Solution group representations as quantum symmetries of graphs, J. Lond. Math. Soc. (2) 106 (2022), no. 4, 3379-–3410. MR4524201
[10] S. Wang, Quantum symmetry groups of finite spaces, Comm. Math. Phys. 195 (1998), 195–211.

I would draw attention to anything connected to Einstein manifolds. While proposed more than fifty years ago, it is a very active area of research in physics and mathematics, so I think one could argue it is, at least partially, modern.
The concept of Einstein manifolds came directly from Einstein's theory of general relativity. The Einstein condition on a smooth Riemannian manifold is given by:
$\text{Ric} = kg$
In physics, this condition represents a solution to the Einstein field equations in a vacuum, possibly with a cosmological constant. Thus, Einstein manifolds had its origins in physics.
This physics-driven concept intrigued mathematicians, who were, and continue to be, fascinated by:

Sign variations of $ k $: Different signs (i.e. positive, negative, or zero) leads to varying curvature properties, which affect the global structure of the manifold.

Dimensional challenges: The complexity of constructing Einstein manifolds, and the observation of exotic structures, can increase or decrease depending on the dimension. For example, understanding compact Einstein manifolds in four dimensions presents immense difficulty.

Compact construction: Constructing compact Einstein manifolds is especially tough, and thus represents a rich area of mathematical research.


Moving forward, the impact of mathematical breakthrough provided by physics increased, as gauge theory began to take centre stage. Edward Witten's work on Seiberg-Witten theory, a supersymmetric gauge theory in physics, opened new doors to understanding 4-manifolds, including Einstein manifolds in the fourth dimension. Witten discovered that Seiberg-Witten invariants could be sued to study 4-manifolds, providing a more accessible alternative to Donaldson invariants for proofs and analysis of 4-manifolds. The transition marked a major advance, as these invariants allowed mathematicians to prove results on 4-dimensional Einstein manifolds, which were previously out of reach.
Another example of where physics has continued to increase understanding in this field is provided in the way that gauge theory, in particular now that it has been converted into a more pure mathematical language in this context, has led to research in using numerical analysis for the construction of Einstein metrics. Physicist' methods of rewriting equations in gauge notation has led to computational techniques to simulate and study Einstein metrics, helping to generate potential examples.
